# Write a program to add ten numbers enter by user in a loop. (For loo

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

```
# Task 4: Take ten number from user in a loop and find the largest number
List=[]
for i in range(1,11):
    List.append(print(int(input("Enter only integer value::"))))
a= List[0]
for x in range(10):
    if a < List[x]:
        print(a, "Is the largest number")
```

Comment: The `print()` buried inside the first `for` loop is where the problem is.

Comment: print() statements return none, so calling the print inside the append returns none, making the append record none each time

Comment: Also your logic makes no sense.  If `a` is LESS THAN the current list element, why are you printing that it is the LARGEST number?

Comment: Also, did you mean to write: `print(max(int(input("Enter only integer value::")) for _ in range(10)))`?

Comment: @quamrana Pretty sure this person is a beginner, so no, that isn't what they meant to type.

Comment: @JohnGordon: Ok, maybe I went too far. Once you start down the rabbit hole its difficult to stop.

Comment: Do you want to add ten numbers or find the largest number?

Answer (score 3):

`print()` always returns `None`.  So your List contains a bunch of None values.

`input()` takes care of printing the prompt, so you don't need `print()` anyway.

Change your append loop to take out the `print()`:

```
List.append(int(input("Enter only integer value::")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a print inside your input like @JohnGordon said. You also have to iterate through `a`. You are currently only measuring the 1st value in your `list` by indexing.